# running AdPredictor (online learning) on a categorical dataset

Tags: python, pandas, logistic-regression, online-machine-learning

I am working on the [dry bean dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/dataset/602/dry+bean+dataset), and only use categorical features.

Moreover, I changed the target from categorical to binary (0,1) and have the data as a pandas dataframe.

I already did logistic regression etc.

Now I'd like to run an online learning model on the data - specifically I'd like to run [AdPredictor](https://github.com/ajtulloch/adpredictor).

Unfortunately I am not able to reproduce the code there - and am wondering if there is another suggested way how to implement it or any suggestions what to do.

It is very important for me to run an online learning model - preferably AdPredictor.